# Change x-axis legend font size in ssrs 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I m using SSRS 2005 to develop reports. But I failed to change x-axis  legends font size.

It have been showing default font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size of either the X-Axis or Y-Axis, by clicking on Style Properties button next to Show Labels section.

[image]

You can select the font size and other attributes from here....

[image]